# What is "uses allocator" and "scoped allocator" construction in c++

Tags: c++, uses-allocator

There are quite a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uses_allocator) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scoped_allocator) on here which talk about [uses allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator#Uses-allocator_construction) and [scoped allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor) but they come from an assumption of knowing what these are and what they are for.

The explanation in the usual C++ references explains the what but not so much the how or why.

This site is missing a canonical answer that will provide the background for those unfamiliar with the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a protocol that allows generic container types (in the broader sense of the word) to detect when generic type parameters expect to be using with allocators.

They can then decide to support that by automatically propagating their outside allocators to the inner types. The quintessential example would be when you want to have a `std::map<std::vector<std::string>, std::set<int> >` all using the same allocator family.

Types containing a nested `allocator_type` typename will automatically be detected as `uses_allocator` types, which includes all standard containers.

Typical other `uses_allocator` types in the standard library are `std::pair` and `std::tuple`, but also function wrapper types (`std::function`, `std::packaged_type`) and container adaptors (`std::stack` and friends).

Scoped allocators allow adapting an outer allocator or an outer allocator and set of inner allocators if they are not identical, informing a scoped-allocator-aware container of the allocator types to be used for inner "uses-allocator" types.

From the boost documentation for `scoped_allocator_adaptor`:

> This class is a C++03-compatible implementation of `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`.
> The class template `scoped_allocator_adaptor` is an allocator template that specifies
> the memory resource (the outer allocator) to be used by a container (as any other
> allocator does) and also specifies an inner allocator resource to be passed to
> the constructor of every element within the container.
>
> This adaptor is instantiated with one outer and zero or more inner allocator
> types. If instantiated with only one allocator type, the inner allocator
> becomes the `scoped_allocator_adaptor` itself, thus using the same allocator
> resource for the container and every element within the container and, if the
> elements themselves are containers, each of their elements recursively.
>
> If instantiated with more than one allocator, the first allocator is the
> outer allocator for use by the container, the second allocator is passed to
> the constructors of the container's elements, and, if the elements themselves
> are containers, the third allocator is passed to the elements' elements, and
> so on. If containers are nested to a depth greater than the number of
> allocators, the last allocator is used repeatedly, as in the single-allocator
> case, for any remaining recursions.

In my experience, Boost Container has always supported this protocol better than most standard library implementations, but I admit I haven't checked up on the state of those in years.

I've just provided you with an example of using `scoped_allocator_adaptor` in  this answer: [Does boost interprocess support sharing objects containing pointers between processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72310393/does-boost-interprocess-support-sharing-objects-containing-pointers-between-proc/72312694#72312694). In that picture, `Shared::Bar` is an example of an inner "uses-allocator" type, and it informs the container (`vector`) to pass a (converted) copy of its allocator along when constructing elements.

I replicate that answer's code listing here, to make sure the example reference doesn't get out of date:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dece79f14055b92)**

```
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <string>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

namespace Shared {
#ifdef COLIRU
    using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file;
#else
    using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
#endif
    using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor< //
        bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;

    template <typename T> using Vector = std::vector<T, Alloc<T>>;

    using String = boost::container::basic_string< //
        char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    struct Bar {
        using allocator_type = Alloc<char>;
        String first_name, last_name;

        template <typename Alloc>
        Bar(std::allocator_arg_t, Alloc alloc) : first_name(alloc)
                                               , last_name(alloc) {}

        template <typename Alloc>
        Bar(Alloc&& alloc) : first_name(alloc)
                           , last_name(alloc) {}

        Bar(Bar const&) = default;
        template <typename Alloc>
        Bar(Bar const& rhs, Alloc alloc) : first_name(rhs.first_name, alloc), last_name(rhs.last_name, alloc) {}

        Bar& operator=(Bar const&) = default;

        template <typename Alloc> Bar(std::string_view first_name, std::string_view last_name, Alloc alloc) : 
            first_name(first_name, alloc), last_name(last_name, alloc) {}
    };

    struct Snafu {
        std::array<int, 5> no_problem;
    };

    struct Foo {
        Vector<Bar>   bars;
        Vector<Snafu> snafus;

        template <typename Alloc> //
        Foo(Alloc alloc) : bars(alloc)
                         , snafus(alloc) {}
    };
}

#include <iostream>
static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shared::Foo const& foo) {
    os << "Foo\n================\nBars:\n";
    for (auto& [f, l] : foo.bars)
        os << " - " << f << ", " << l << "\n";

    os << "Snafus:";
    for (auto& s : foo.snafus) {
        os << "\n - ";
        for (auto el : s.no_problem)
            os << " " << el;
    }
    return os << "\n";
}


int main() { Shared::Segment msm(bip::open_or_create, "my_shared_mem", 10ull << 10);
    Shared::Foo& foo = *msm.find_or_construct<Shared::Foo>("the_foo") //
                        (msm.get_segment_manager()); // constructor arguments

    foo.bars.emplace_back("John", "Doe");
    foo.bars.emplace_back("Jane", "Deer");
    foo.bars.emplace_back("Igor", "Stravinsky");
    foo.bars.emplace_back("Rimsky", "Korsakov");

    foo.snafus.push_back({1, 2, 3});
    foo.snafus.push_back({2, 3, 4});
    foo.snafus.push_back({3, 4, 5, 6, 7});

    std::cout << foo << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Though you have using Alloc clauses you don't actually use [std::uses_allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator#Uses-allocator_construction) in this answer. Is it implicit somewhere? or is that unrelated?

Comment: It's implicit because a nested typename `allocator_type` is present.

Comment: I was trying to understand the history of this feature and found - [p0591r4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0591r4.pdf) has a nice explanation of how its changed in C++20.